# how do I loop through a line from a csv file in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to process a csv file in powershell, but I don't know what the column headings in the CSV file will be when it is processed.

For example:

```
$path = "d:\scratch\export.csv"
$csv = Import-csv -path $path

foreach($line in $csv)
{ 
    foreach ($head in $line | get-member | where-object {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"} | select Definition)
    {
        #pseudocode...
        doSomething($head.columnName, $head.value)
    }

}
```

How do I loop through the line in the csv file, getting the name of the column and the value? Or is there another way I should be doing this (like not using Import-csv)?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
Import-Csv $path | Foreach-Object { 

    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties)
    {
        doSomething $property.Name, $property.Value
    } 

}
```

Comment: This skipped the first line for me. I am not using headers in my csv and I only have one row with no commas ex: thing1<NEWLINE>thing2<NEWLINE> ect.. In other words a simple list

Comment: @Radmation Import-CSV $path -Header A is the change you need. This tells powershell to add the header "A" to the column and treat every row as a value, rather than thinking row 1 is a header row.

Comment: Important difference using `ForEach-Object` instead of a simple `ForEach` when working with CSV.

Comment: @unNamed No, it does not matter at all.

Answer (score 20):

A slightly other way of iterating through each column of each line of a CSV-file would be

```
$path = "d:\scratch\export.csv"
$csv = Import-Csv -path $path

foreach($line in $csv)
{ 
    $properties = $line | Get-Member -MemberType Properties
    for($i=0; $i -lt $properties.Count;$i++)
    {
        $column = $properties[$i]
        $columnvalue = $line | Select -ExpandProperty $column.Name

        # doSomething $column.Name $columnvalue 
        # doSomething $i $columnvalue 
    }
}
```

so you have the choice: you can use either `$column.Name` to get the name of the column, or `$i` to get the number of the column

Comment: Get-Member sorts the columns alphabetically.  If the original order of the CSV columns is required, it will be lost.

Answer (score 3):

```
$header3 = @("Field_1","Field_2","Field_3","Field_4","Field_5")     

Import-Csv $fileName -Header $header3 -Delimiter "`t" | select -skip 3 | Foreach-Object {

    $record = $indexName 
    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties){

        #doSomething $property.Name, $property.Value

            if($property.Name -like '*TextWrittenAsNumber*'){

                $record = $record + "," + '"' + $property.Value + '"' 
            }
            else{
                $record = $record + "," + $property.Value 
            }                           
    }               

        $array.add($record) | out-null  
        #write-host $record                         
}
```

Comment: What does `select -skip 3` do?

Answer (score 0):

The Import-Csv takes the columns' names. ForEach-Object processes them. You can take the column value by "$_.COLNAME".

Example code that takes the ATTACHMENT.csv and creates directories with the values of "DIRNAME" column, then moves the item "ATTACHMENT" to this directory.

---

```
Import-Csv .\ATTACHMENT.csv -Delimiter "," | ForEach-Object -Process {New-Item -Path "." -Name ($_.DIRNAME) -ItemType "directory"; Move-Item ($_.ATTACHMENT) -Destination (".\" + $_.DIRNAME + "\" + $_.ATTACHMENT)}
```