# How to convert .xls to .csv using Powershell without Excel installed

Tags: excel, powershell

Is there a way to convert .xls to .csv without Excel being installed using Powershell?

I don't have access to Excel on a particular machine so I get an error when I try:

```
New-Object -ComObject excel.application
```

> New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: I'm not proficient enough with PowerShell to provide a full answer, but I think you can connect to the Excel file as an Odbc data source, even without Excel installed, and dump the results of a select query from that datasource to csv. The trick is knowing the name of the sheet(s). Also, what do you want to do if there is more than worksheet?

Comment: there will only every be one sheet.

Comment: Found an example of what Joel was talking about here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670082/Use-Excel-in-PowerShell-without-a-full-version-of and another one http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/11/how-can-i-read-from-excel-without-using-excel.aspx

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [powershell excel access without installing Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011481/powershell-excel-access-without-installing-excel)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Forward**

Depending on what you already have installed on your system you might need the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) for this solution to work. That will give you access to the provider: "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

**Disclaimer**: Not super impressed with the result and someone with more background could make this answer better but here it goes.

**Code**

```powershell
$strFileName = "C:\temp\Book1.xls"
$strSheetName = 'Sheet1$'
$strProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
$strDataSource = "Data Source = $strFileName"
$strExtend = "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
$strQuery = "Select * from [$strSheetName]"

$objConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("$strProvider;$strDataSource;$strExtend")
$sqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($strQuery)
$sqlCommand.Connection = $objConn
$objConn.open()

$da = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($sqlCommand)
$dt = New-Object system.Data.datatable
[void]$da.fill($dt)

$dataReader.close()
$objConn.close()

$dt
```

Create an ODBC connection to the excel file `$strFileName`. You need to know your sheet name and populate  `$strSheetName` which helps build `$strQuery`. When then use several objects to create a connection and extract the data from the sheet as a `System.Data.DataTable`. In my test file, with one populated sheet, I had two columns of data.  After running the code the output of `$dt` is:

```
letter number
------ ------
a           2
d          34
b           0
e           4
```

You could then take that table and then `ExportTo-CSV`

```
$dt | Export-Csv c:\temp\data.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This was built based on information gathered from:

1. [Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/11/how-can-i-read-from-excel-without-using-excel.aspx)
2. [PowerShell Code Repository](http://poshcode.org/1591)