# why do I get a null valued expression error when converting a csv file to excel using powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a powershell script that downloads a CSV file from yahoo finance, and my goal is to convert it to an excel file (.xlsx). The script is:

```
$path = "D:"

$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=EDV,VEA,VWO,VHT,BND,VTI&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv"
$csv_filename = Join-Path $path "prices.csv"
$client.DownloadFile($url, $csv_filename)

$xl_filename = Join-Path $path "prices.xlsx"

$xl = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
$xl.Visible = $true

$wb = $xl.Workbooks.OpenText($csv_filename)
$wb.SaveAs($xl_filename, 51)
$wb.Close()

$xl.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
```

The script is located in `D:\get_prices.ps1' and I execute it with

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File D:\get_prices.ps1

When I run it I get two errors:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\get_prices.ps1:14 char:11
+ $wb.SaveAs <<<< ($xl_filename, 51)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (SaveAs:String) [], RuntimeExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\get_prices.ps1:15 char:10
+ $wb.Close <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Close:String) [], RuntimeExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The conversion code is adapted from this question-answer ([How to export a CSV to Excel using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688468/how-to-export-a-csv-to-excel-using-powershell)).

I looked at the documentation for [Workbook.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and as far as I nkow Im using it correctly, and the file format (the `51` argument) is correct too based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017%28v=office.15%29.aspx). I also looked at the docs for [Workbook.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838613%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and that all looks correct too.

I'm using powershell v2.0 (according to `get-host`) and Excel 2013 on Windows 7 x64.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$xl.Workbooks.OpenText` returns void not a workbook.

Make this change:

```
$xl.Workbooks.OpenText($csv_filename)
$wb=$xl.ActiveWorkbook
```