# How to open (import) .CSV into Excel using CMD

Tags: excel, csv, cmd

I found a sort-of answer here:

https://superuser.com/questions/730249/run-command-to-open-csv-file-in-excel

But it's not enough to simply use excel to open my .CSV file; I want to import the .csv data into the excel worksheet (I can do it using the wizard built into excel if I open the program manually), but I want to do this all strictly using CMD.  I have previously generated a .csv file using SQLCMD but I couldn't generate it into an excel file, so I'm trying to do this all in 2 steps instead.

Comment: maybe [this](https://superuser.com/a/1222081/217811) is helpful?

Comment: @Stephan thanks - it's not quite the solution I'm looking for, but there is some useful information in there. I could always try new approaches again.

Comment: With PowerShell and the [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.4.0) module (even without excel installed)  you could possibly have it in a single step - at a learning curve of course.

Comment: @LotPings I will definitely look into this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a powershell version of what I need here: [How to export a CSV to Excel using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688468/how-to-export-a-csv-to-excel-using-powershell).

I made my own adjustments to fit my needs, but it worked perfectly! And I learned how to call this powershell script from my cmd/batch file so I think this will work.