# how to convert txt to xls using cmd

Tags: excel, text, converters

I want to convert the result file txt which columns are separated in pipes (|) to an excel file spreedsheet.

I don't want to use Excel app. I need to do it via batch file.

what is the best option? I was thinking in an external app but I don't know which is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about batch, but if you have access to PowerShell, the information here may help:

[How to export a CSV to Excel using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688468/how-to-export-a-csv-to-excel-using-powershell)

Comment: not useful for me, I saw this solution. I need to set the batch file to run the task in windows and I think windows use for thar batch file as cmd