# Convert CSV (tab delimited) to Excel using command line

Tags: excel, bash, powershell, csv, automator

I have 100s files in the following format:

`Jan    20    21:42:36     123UH9887934     [process name]     text     text    text    text`

tab delimited.

all of them in a dir; many entries per file; in the same format.

I'd like to use a bash or Powershell or even Mac Automator script, to convert them to Excel format.

Importing into Excel just puts all the data into one cell. And is manual.

The problem is that most scripts assume commas as delimiter so they put all the data into one cell.

If I open the files one-by-one in Numbers it understands the tab delimiters and formats it correctly.  It just takes forever.

I've Tried Powershell:
`Import-Csv "VQ18072500JPJ.csv" | Format-Table` but can't quite figure out how it wants me to convert and save to a new file.

I've tried Bash:  `for file in ./*.csv do ssconvert -O "separator='   ' $file ${file%.csv}.xls; done` but it doesn't understand the delimiters either.

Any ideas on how to get 100s of tab delimited CSVs converted with a script would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please update the question to show the expected output (corresponding to the sample input)

Comment: in one place, your code makes it seem that you want to convert tab-delimited csv to XLS file format. in another sentence you seem to ant to convert tab-delimited csv to comma-delimited csv. _what do you actually want?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sole objective is to covert tabs to commas:

```
$ tr '\t' ',' < file.csv
Jan,20,21:42:36,123UH9887934,[process name],text,text,text,text

$ awk -v OFS=, '{$1=$1}1' file.csv
Jan,20,21:42:36,123UH9887934,[process,name],text,text,text,text

$ sed 's/\t/,/g' file.csv
Jan,20,21:42:36,123UH9887934,[process name],text,text,text,text
```

Comment: In the example data I did not see a comma, but I would expect ont in the 100's of files. Suggest a check `grep "," *csv` first. When the data is without double quotes: 
`sed `s/.*/"&"/; s/\t/"&"/g' file`. Data with double quotes: check if they are at the next to a TAB or in the middle of a field.

Comment: the awk is what worked for me.  Thanks marks-fuso.

Answer (score 0):

When your csv file starts with a line `SEP=x`, the character x will be used by Excel as the field separator. Replace the x with a real TAB.

```
for f in *.csv; do
  sed -i '1s/^/SEP=\t\n/' "$f"
done
```

Perhaps you can use PowerShell with the code given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21169406/3220113
Perhaps change one line into

```
$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = "`t"
```