# excelcnv command line options

Tags: excel, csv, command-line-arguments, converters

I found posts that recommended `excelcnv.exe` as a way to convert a CSV file to an Excel file, e.g. [How to export a CSV to Excel using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56159131/4919610), which uses the command line switches `-nme` and `-oice`.

Does anybody know what these switches do? And are there more switches available?

I couldn't find any documentation on `excelcnv.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](https://www.hexacorn.com/blog/2021/05/23/excellent-conversions-and-downloads/) might help you. The author lists some command line switches but does not go into detail how he found out about them.