# Convert CSV to XLSX using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

not a super strong powershell guy.I am trying to convert a CSV file to XLSX using Powershell. With the code below i can only save it as XLS not XLSX. If i put "$Workbook.SaveAs(“c:\sdk\AdEmployeeNumber.xlsX”,1)" excel thinks the file is corrupted.

```
$xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
$xl.visible = $true`enter code here`
$Workbook = $xl.workbooks.open(“c:\sdk\AdEmployeeNumber.csv”)
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets
$Workbook.SaveAs(“c:\sdk\AdEmployeeNumber.xls”,1)
$Workbook.Saved = $True
$xl.Quit()
```

Comment: Try `$Workbook.SaveAs(“c:\sdk\AdEmployeeNumber.xlsx”,51)`

Comment: If you want to give [`ImportExcel` Module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) a try this task is as easy as `Import-Csv .\source.csv | Export-Excel .\destination.xlsx`

Comment: Pass it a proper excel file format. `$Workbook.SaveAs("c:\sdk\AdEmployeeNumber.xlsx",[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook)`

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688468/how-to-export-a-csv-to-excel-using-powershell) has a couple solutions that may help you.