# Save powershel log to .xlsx

Tags: powershell, xlsx

I have this powershell code and I need it to save the log generated in `.xlsx` because I intend to work simultaneously.
Thanks!

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\iguaracu_pr"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
                $path = $path -replace ".{4}$"
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$changeType, $path"
                Add-content "C:\Users\admin\Pictures\Duvidas\log.csv" -value $logline
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export a CSV to Excel using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688468/how-to-export-a-csv-to-excel-using-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at the `ImportExcel` module - see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/ and https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/ - this uses a .net library so you don't need Excel installed. Discover how to use the module with `Get-Command -Module ImportExcel | Sort-Object Noun`.

In case you cannot install modules, see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688850/6274530) - this uses COM to open Excel and invoke it through Powershell. You will need Excel installed locally.

### How to discover how to use an object

*In case you need to develop a solution using Excel through COM*

Generally, I explore objects with `Get-Member`. Members of type `Method` can be invoked, e.g. with `$Workbook.SaveAs("C:\foo.xlsx")`. Here's an example of discovering how to use the `Process.WaitForExit` method with a timeout:

```
/gitroot ❯ $p = Get-Process kitty

/gitroot ❯ $p | Get-Member W*    

   TypeName: System.Diagnostics.Process

Name             MemberType    Definition
----             ----------    ----------
WS               AliasProperty WS = WorkingSet64
WaitForExit      Method        void WaitForExit(), bool WaitForExit(int milliseconds), bool WaitForExit(timespan timeout)
WaitForExitAsync Method        System.Threading.Tasks.Task WaitForExitAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
WaitForInputIdle Method        bool WaitForInputIdle(), bool WaitForInputIdle(int milliseconds), bool WaitForInputIdle(timespan timeout)
WorkingSet       Property      int WorkingSet {get;}
WorkingSet64     Property      long WorkingSet64 {get;}


/gitroot ❯ $p.WaitForExit(200)
False
```

---

As a rule, I suggest using `Export-Csv -Append` instead of `Add-Content` - CSV can be tricky with quoting.

```
$Action = {
    $LogEntry = [pscustomobject]@{
        ChangeType = [string]$Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        Path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name -replace ".{4}$"
    }
    $LogEntry | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\admin\Pictures\Duvidas\log.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```