# Simple PowerShell Script to loop through 1 CSV file to create a new CSV file from another

Tags: powershell

I know the title sounds confusing, but once I describe this, I'm certain there is a very easy way to perform what I need to do.  I'm very new to PowerShell and am trying to perform a specific task that seems rather difficult to find a good answer for one the Web.

I have spent the past several days searching through methods of concatenating the data and joining the files together, but nothing that was specific enough to this task.  All examples show how to display data, but nothing that loops through and adds data together to create a new csv file.  If anything, I've over-researched this issue to the point of having to pose this message to see where I can get my brain de-cluttered with all of the useless options I've already tried...

I have two csv files.  I call them csv's, but they are really just a single column of information each.

Files:

**Users.csv**

**Offices.csv**

The **Users.csv** file has a list of network user names.  The **Offices.csv** file has a list of numbers that correspond to office locations.

What I want to have happen is to use a loop that will take each user from the users.csv file and create a new line in a separate csv file the adds each of the offices to it.

EXAMPLE:

**Users.csv**

```
NTNAME
domain\user1
domain\user2
domain\user3
```

**Offices.csv**

```
OFFICES
0001
0023
0043
0067
```

When combined, I would like csv file that looks like this:

```
NTNAME,OFFICES
domain\user1,0001
domain\user1,0023
domain\user1,0043
domain\user1,0067
domain\user2,0001
domain\user2,0023
domain\user2,0043
domain\user2,0067
domain\user3,0001
domain\user3,0023
domain\user3,0043
domain\user3,0067
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing Shay's awesome [CSV field enumeration code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11885405/1630171):

```
$offices = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\offices.csv'

Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\users.csv' | % {
  foreach ($prop in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
    $offices | select @{n=$prop.Name;e={$prop.Value}}, OFFICES
  }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\combined.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This worked out exactly as I needed it to.  Thanks very much!  The only thing that I'll need to add is a method to remove the quote marks from the results so that it's automated.  I can figure that part out on my own.