# Unable to get CSV Row count in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, count

I have a csv file that's structured like this:

```
Text,Url
Learning Haskell,https://wiki.haskell.org/Learning_Haskell
```

I'm attempting to get the row count before I loop over the csv file, because I don't want to start a loop on empty results.

From researching ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32888812/10597450),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19779851/10597450)), it would seem that `Import-csv` has a `.Count` property, but for some reason I'm unable to access that property. I'm using Powershell v5.

**Code:**

```
[string]$markdownlink = "markdownlinks.csv"
[string]$processedLinks = "completedlinks.txt"

$markdownlinkstoProcess = Import-Csv $markdownlink -Delimiter "," 

# Returns 0
[int]$count=$markdownlinkstoProcess.Count
Write-output $count
```

Comment: You could do `$markdownlinkstoProcess.GetLength(0)` or `@($markdownlinkstoProcess.GetEnumerator()).Count` to get the number of rows in the csv. `$markdownlinkstoProcess.GetUpperBound(0) + 1` should also do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you have ONE data row in a CSV file, the import produces a *single* object. **that has a known bug in that it will report zero as the `.Count` of the $Var.** this appears to happen with *anything* that returns a single PSCustomObject - but i aint sure of that.

the solution is to *force* it to be an array. you can cast it as `[array]` or simply wrap it in `@()`. using your code for an example ...

```
$markdownlinkstoProcess = Import-Csv $markdownlink -Delimiter ","
$markdownlinkstoProcess.GetType()
# result = PSCustomObject
$markdownlinkstoProcess.Count
# result = 0

$markdownlinkstoProcess = @(Import-Csv $markdownlink -Delimiter ",")
$markdownlinkstoProcess.GetType()
# result = Object[]
$markdownlinkstoProcess.Count
# result = 1
```