# Convert Import-CSV result from string to arbitrary data types

Tags: csv, powershell

Suppose I read in a CSV file from PowerShell:

```
$data = Import-Csv "myfilename.csv"
```

CSV files (in general) can contain strings and numbers, but PowerShell stores them in memory as strings:

```
PS D:\> $data[0].Col3.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

After importing, it would be useful to be able to convert the types from string. If there are only one or two columns then I can convert them using a calculated property as follows:

```
$data = Import-Csv "myfilename.csv" |
        select -Property @{n='Col2';e={[int]$_.Col2}},
            @{n='Col3';e={[double]$_.Col3}}
```

But suppose I don't know in advance the column names and intended types. Instead I have an arbitrary "schema" telling me which columns should be which type, for example:

```
$Schema = @{Col1=[string];Col2=[int];Col3=[double]}
```

How can I convert the output from Import-CSV to the types as determined by the schema? (And preferably in an efficient/elegant way)

**Sample CSV file**

```
"Col1","Col2","Col3"
"a",2,4.3
"b",5,7.9
```

Comment: Note, this question is significantly different to a previous one I posted (and subsequently deleted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `-as` cast:

```
$data = Import-Csv "myfilename.csv" |
        select -Property @{n='Col2';e={$_.Col2 -as $Schema.Col2}},
            @{n='Col3';e=$_.Col3 -as $Schema.Col3}}
```

For an arbitrary number of columns you can extend the approach outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11885405/1630171) to a similar question:

```
$data = Import-Csv "myfilename.csv" | Foreach-Object { 
          foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
            $property.Value = $property.Value -as $Schema[$property.Name]
          }
          $_   # return the modified object
        }
```

Comment: How can that work with an arbitary $Schema, for example you don't know in advance how many columns there are in the $Schema

Comment: you could either use the column name to access the hash value using `$Schema[COLUMN_NAME]` or you define an `array`and access the specific column by an index.

Comment: So sounds like you are proposing a for loop over the column names - can you edit the code to reflect this?

Comment: I think you already almost had that code in your previous post which you somehow deleted?

Comment: Let's work together to get an answer then: I previously had     $data = Import-Csv "myfilename.csv" | % { 
        foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties)
        {
            $property.Value = [double]$property.Value; $_
        } 
    }

Comment: Well, now you can use the colum name to access the hash value? Anway, I think this question is answered. You should probably create another question if you have any further questions.

Comment: `$data = Import-Csv "myfilename.csv" | % { foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) { $property.Value = $property.Value -as $Schema[property.Name]; $_ } }` then?

Comment: If you edit the post to include the looping through the schema then I'm happy to mark as answered, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I expanded upon Martin Brandl's great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36472670/5405967) here in two ways:

1. First, it can handle more complex cases.  Instead of having the schema be a hash table of data types, I generalized it to be a hash table of conversion functions.  This allows you to do non-trivial data-type conversions as well as per-column pre-processing/clean-up.
2. I also flipped the for-each logic so that it iterates through the schema keys instead of the object's properties.  That way, your schema doesn't need to contain every field, which is helpful if you have a CSV with many string fields that can be left alone and just a few fields that need data type conversion.

In the example below:

- The text column is purposefully left out of the schema to demonstrate that that's ok.
- The memory column is converted from bytes to kilobytes.
- The third column is converted from sloppy strings to booleans.

Example

```
$testData = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Text = 'A'; MemoryWithConversion = 10*1024; BooleanText="yes"},
    [PSCustomObject]@{Text = 'B'; MemoryWithConversion = 20*1024; BooleanText="no"},
    [PSCustomObject]@{Text = 'C'; MemoryWithConversion = 30*1024; BooleanText=""}
)
$testData | Export-Csv 'test.csv'
    
$schema = @{
    MemoryWithConversion = {Param($value) $value / 1kB -as [int]}
    BooleanText = {Param($value) $value -in 'true', 't', 'yes', 'y' -as [boolean]}
}

Import-Csv 'test.csv' | Foreach-Object { 
    foreach ($key in $schema.Keys) {
        $property = $_.PSObject.Properties[$key]
        if ($property -ne $null) {
            $property.Value = & $schema[$property.Name] $property.Value
        }
    }
    $_
}
```

Result

```
Text MemoryWithConversion BooleanText
---- -------------------- -----------
A                      10        True
B                      20       False
C                      30       False
```